# SQLite - migrating linked data, how to avoid hard-coded primary keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I'm writing SQL migration for SQLite DB and I have linked tables, so I have to insert 'root' table row first and then to insert 'children' rows which will use ID for 'root' row.

One option could be to hard-code primary key of the 'root' row and reuse it later in all dependent rows, but I don't like to risk having 'duplicate ID' errors.

I know there's 'last_insert_rowid' in SQLite and I can use temporary table to save this value for the following inserts, but still maybe I'm missing more optimal way to do it.

For example I have tables:

- Plant(id)
- PlantDescription(id, language_id, plant_id, desctiption)
- PlantLink(id, language_id, plant_id, link)

and I want the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO Plant VALUES (123);
INSERT INTO PlantDescription VALUES (1, 1, 123, 'some description');
INSERT INTO PlantLink VALUES (1, 1, 123, 'http://eng-link.com');
```

Here to insert PlantDescription and PlantLink I need to know primary ID of previously inserted Plant.

I'm looking for the best practice to achieve that. 
I'm developing Android app and using Android Room, but probably the question is more general and any SQLite solution should fit.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is quite unclear why you need to change the values of the keys at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've added an example, please take a look. I'm not sure I understood your point about changing values of the keys (I don't want it)